# Django abstract model field depends on children attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I want to code some model structure containing abstract parent model and child models with same fields but different names, help_text and related_name. How better and shorter implement this behavior? Is there any solutions at all?

```python
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    name = None
    code = None
    rel_field = models.OneToOneField(RelatedModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     primary_key=True, related_name=code)
    field = models.CharField(name, null=True,
                             help_text=HELP_DICT.get(code, None))


class ChildOne(AbstractModel):
    name = "child one name"
    code = "one"


class ChildTwo(AbstractModel):
     name = "child two name"
     code = "two"
     child_field = SomeAnotherField()
```

I want to make

```python
ChildOne.field == models.CharField("child one name", help_text=HELP_DICT.get("one", None) ...)
ChildTwo.field == models.CharField("child two name", help_text=HELP_DICT.get("two", None) ...)
```

and

```python
RelatedModel.one == ChildOne
RelatedModel.two == ChildTwo
```